# Show the average value of a group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, average

My MySQL table contains a field that stores the user’s weight and a date field. I am trying to make a query that shows the average weight for a week.

My query so far looks like this:

```
SELECT Table.`id`,
       Table.`weight`,
       Table.`date`
FROM Table
WHERE id=%CURRENT_USER_ID%
ORDER BY date ASC
GROUP BY week(date);
```

This query generates a list where the results are grouped by week.
But I also need the average weight for each week. Right now it only shows the weight for one entry.

How can I make this query?

Comment: Use `AVG(weight)`

Answer (score 1):

Be careful. Your SQL is not valid, even though MySQL can be configured to allow it.

This is an issue of `functional dependence`.  The `SELECT` list terms must be `functionally dependent` on the `GROUP BY` terms.

You've selected `id`, which is not functionally dependent on `week(date)`.  In other words, your schema/logic does not guarantee that there is at most one `id` value per `week(date)` group.  The same is true of trying to select `date`, which is also not guaranteed to resolve to just one value per week.

Your `WHERE` clause is also a problem.  `%` can be used as a pattern in a `LIKE` expression, but not with the `=` operator, and was not properly quoted as a literal. I'll leave `'CURRENT_USER_ID'` to represent your value, assuming that's the correct type. The table definition wasn't shown in the question.

A corrected version of your original query is:

```
SELECT week(`date`)  AS the_week
     , MIN(`weight`) AS min_weight
     , MIN(`id`)     AS min_id
  FROM Table
 WHERE id='CURRENT_USER_ID'
 GROUP BY week(date)
 ORDER BY the_week ASC
;
```

Note: The above uses the aggregate function `MIN` in the `SELECT` list.  These expressions are functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY` terms.  The `AVG` function can also be used, like this:

```
SELECT week(`date`)  AS the_week
     , AVG(`weight`) AS avg_weight
  FROM Table
 WHERE id='CURRENT_USER_ID'
 GROUP BY week(date)
 ORDER BY the_week ASC
;
```

and in MySQL, we can use the derived column name / alias in the `GROUP BY` terms.

```
SELECT week(`date`)  AS the_week
     , AVG(`weight`) AS avg_weight
  FROM Table
 WHERE id='CURRENT_USER_ID'
 GROUP BY the_week
 ORDER BY the_week ASC
;
```

That's a start.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a little changing and get your desired output.
use this

```
 SELECT Table.`id`,
       Table.`weight`,
       Table.`date`,
       Avg('Table.weight')'Average Weight'
FROM Table
WHERE id=%CURRENT_USER_ID%
ORDER BY date ASC
GROUP BY week(date);
```